# why Ubuntuone takes 4GB of RAM memory

Tags: ubuntu-one, ram, memory-usage

see the detail

[image]

env: ubuntu 11.10 x64

Answer (score 3):

Because you interpret 'used memory' the wrong way. In Linux `unused memory = bad memory`, so Linux tries to use every available memory if possible. An example is caching. This memory can be freed up anytime as soon as an application needs it.

You can flush these cached contents manually:

```
# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1022560     470596     551964          0      27872     189784
-/+ buffers/cache:     252940     769620
Swap:      6587388          0    6587388

# sync
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1022560     300952     721608          0        972      53216
-/+ buffers/cache:     246764     775796
Swap:      6587388          0    6587388
```

Comment: it's temporary, i want to solve the problem.

Comment: Is a software design problem, or is my system configuration issues.It makes me very disappointed.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough. It is not a problem. It is a feature, which helps your computer respond fast. The problem is with `htop` which displays memory a confusing way. Look at `free`'s "-/+ buffers/cache" row, which stays almost the same before and after freeing cached memory. That is your **free** memory where "free" means "can be used any time".

Comment: In that top output, RSS means it's actual, physical RAM used. This is not the Linux kernel being smart. This is either syncdaemon being dumb, or a few million files being processed.

Comment: LOL, the original question was about memory used by the whole system and not individual tasks... Now I see that 'ubuntuone' is eating up resources.

Answer (score 3):

This might happen if you add many (hundreds of thousands) of files to be synced at once. Outside of that known scenario, if this happens it's a bug and you should either [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug?field.title=why+Ubuntuone+takes+4GB+of+RAM+memory) or [contact support](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/).

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [new public bug for this here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/893432). Other bugs on this keep getting marked private so they are not visible. Please go to the bug and flag as "affects me to" If you need to attach log files so the Ubuntu One team can diagnose the problem, please open a separate bug.